# Failed to load DATE-FNS

Tags: javascript, mime-types, date-fns

I'm trying to use DATE-FNS in a project with HTML and JavaScript, but the module is not working.

I'm using VS Code with the Liver Server extension.

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "Project1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3"  
  }
}
```

My HTML `<head>`:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ToDo List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script type="module"  src="Ui.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/efbd7c5f89.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

When I call it in the script using this:

```js
import { isToday, isThisWeek } from 'date-fns';
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "date-fns". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

So I tried this:

```js
import { isToday, isThisWeek } from './node_modules/date-fns';
```

but got this other error:

> :5500/node_modules/date-fns/:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Where is your `index.html`? The root of your project, or in the `dist/` directory?

Comment: Index.html is in the root directory. The same as the script and css file. I'm not using bundler in this case.

Comment: You are attempting to use uncompiled TS inside a module. You will need to compile the source code to use it in a module script.

Comment: Im not using Ts, but a simple pure javascript..

Comment: You will probably need a bundler like Parcel, Rollup, or Webpack. Vite is nice and it uses Rollup. Just simply run [yarn create vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) and go through the setup. It's really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import the ESM (ECMAScript modules) instead:

```js
import { isThisWeek, isToday } from "./node_modules/date-fns/esm/index.js";

console.log("Today?", isToday(new Date()));        // true
console.log("This Week?", isThisWeek(new Date())); // true
```